# Xamarin doesn't recognise TestCaseSource attribute

Tags: xamarin, testcasesource

Xamarin doesn't recognise TestCaseSource, it says :

The name TestCaseSource doesn't exist in the current context

the way I use it :

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("divider")]
```

I cannot compile because of this.

Comment: TestCaseSource is an NUnit attribute.  Do you have NUnit referenced in your project, with the appropriate Using statements?

Comment: I do! Actually I found out I don't have the good version (not up to date) and I'm trying to update the dll... I went there
http://nunit.org/index.php?p=download
and downloaded
NUnit-2.6.4.msi but it doesn't seem to update it...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't had the latest version of `nunit.framework.dll`.
I downloaded it through NuGet.